# Auto Full Screen Toggle When Video Plays HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I am having video clip which is due to play in Timer when Timer gets tick after few minutes.

What I want is whenever the video starts playing it should automatically go into FullScreen mode and when it stops it, however comes back to position because as soon as Video stops I have Timer Ticked.

I know this requestFullScreen() method but I don't know how to call it when video starts playing?

Any Help will be appreciated!!

Regards and Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var video = document.createElement('video');

video.src = 'urlToVideo.ogg';
video.style.width = window.innerWidth;
video.style.height = window.innerHeight;
video.autoPlay = true;

document.getElementById('video2').appendChild(video);
```

Comment: HI Thanks for response, but I am not sure how do I use it in asp.net? My video goes inside a <div>

Comment: Use this in JS . Your div must be like <div id='video2'></div>

Comment: This is not fullscreen mode, this setting the video fullsize within the page and starting it automaticly. The OP requested the video to be started at an on-tick event correct?

Comment: No. What the name of the element for the onCLick ? ( sorry for my english )

Comment: @MartijndeLangh Yeah...my video is starting on OnTick..I want to play it in FullScreen as soon as it is started

Comment: The script in my answer will accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
video = document.getElementById('video');

function onTick(){
    video.play();
}

video.onPlay = function() {
    if (video.requestFullscreen) {
       video.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
       video.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
       video.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
       video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
};

video.onended = function(e) {
  if(video.exitFullscreen) {
    video.exitFullscreen();
  } else if(video.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    video.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if(video.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    video.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
<script>

window.onload = function(){
    var el = document.getElementById("OnTick"); 
    el.addEventListener("click", function(){
        el.style.display = 'none';
        var videoContener = document.getElementById('video2');
        var video = document.createElement('video');

        videoContener.style.width = window.innerWidth;
        videoContener.style.height = window.innerHeight;

        video.src = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv';
        video.style.width = "100%";
        video.autoPlay = true;
        video.controls = true;

        videoContener.appendChild(video);

    }, false); 
}

</script>
<body style='margin:0px'>
    <div id='video2' style='overflow: hidden;'></div>
    <span id='OnTick' style='width:20px;height:20px;background-color:#323232;display:block'>  </span>
</body>
```

autoplay doesn't work